# Is there a way to use dbt-formatter to automatically reformat all my sql scripts in VS Code?

Tags: sql, formatting, dbt

I'm using dbt as a dwh managing tool and want to reformat all the sql scripts using one style in VS Code. The only working solution I've managed to find is dbt-formatter extension but I have to manually reformat every sql file to achieve desired result. Is there any way to avoid this?

I've tried to set 'format on save' setting and write a task that will save all the sql files in repository but the task isn't working. I've also tried SQLFLuff and Pretty SQL but none worked.

Comment: We use SQLFluff and the CLI command `sqlfluff fix` and that works in most of the cases (even though you might have to run it several times to get to an error-free format). Why did SQLFluff not work in your end? What did you try?

Comment: Sadly SQLFluff can't fix jinja-syntaxed scripts, it was my first and foremost choice.

Comment: It does for us! I believe it depends on how you set your `.sqlfluff` config file, and your VSCode `settings.json` file

Comment: @AleixCC can I ask you to provide your `.sqlfluff` config file?